# Is it possible to display an enumerated list in HTML starting from given position?

Tags: html, css

I have following list of elements:

```
<ol>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
</ol>
```

I want to display the list starting from 'C', like this:

```
C  First item
D  Second item
E  Third item
```

Is it possible? Does the list always have to start from '1', 'a', 'A', etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a start value that can be defined on your list item alongside a type.

```
<ol type="A" start="3">
```

This is the passage taken from http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html.

start = number
Deprecated. For OL only. This attribute specifies the starting number of the first item in an ordered list. The default starting number is "1". Note that while the value of this attribute is an integer, the corresponding label may be non-numeric. Thus, when the list item style is uppercase latin letters (A, B, C, ...), start=3 means "C". When the style is lowercase roman numerals, start=3 means "iii", etc.

And you can experiment yourself using 
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_ol_start

Comment: It should be start="[number]", C is not a number. :D

Comment: Isn't this attribute being reintroduced for HTML5?

Comment: @edeverett HTML5 is not final and won't be mainstream for 5 years. Don't depend on it just yet.

Comment: Thank you. I found comments that this solution is deprecated, but in this case this is not the issue.

Comment: @maksymko; because the number that the list starts at is presentational, I think. There is a replacement in CSS 2.1 to allow the same result, though browser implementations vary, of course. See my answer, below, for an alternative technique using CSS.

Comment: @ricebowl: that's the reason indeed, but in many cases it obviously isn't presentational.

@Adrian Godong: the editor estimates Candidate Recommendation (which is when you are asked to start using it) in 2012 (3 years); however, many parts of the spec are stable enough to start using right now (and that includes @start).

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<ol type="1" start="n">
```

to start a new list at the desired number, where n is your desired start.

Answer (score 1):

The [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html) says there's a `start` attribute to `<ol>`, but it's deprecated. There's a `value` attribute to `<li>` which is deprecated as well. Not quite sure why and what's the suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using the the `<ol type="1" start="3">` notation if you like, since it is, as noted, deprecated in HTML 4.01*. The downside is that the replacement technique isn't that universal, regardless:

```
ol.start-from-three {
list-style-type: none;
counter-reset: list-counter 3; /* resets the counter to 3 */
}

ol.start-from-three li {
}

ol.start-from-three li:before { /* or :after, if you like */
content: "number: counter(list-counter)";
counter-increment: list-counter;
}

<ol class="start-from-three">
<li>This is the first item, numbered third</li>
<li>This is the second  item, numbered fourth</li>
<li>...etc...</li>
</ol>
```

Of course those browsers that will interpret this technique (from [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)) will allow both the deprecated and CSS version. So...maybe, use some form of conditional if you need validation?

---

**Edited** to amend my original assertion that "`<ol type="1" start="3">` is deprecated in html 4.01+", [ms2ger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33466/ms2ger) raised the point, in the comments below, that it was deprecated only in html 4.01, html 5 (for example) allows the `start="`*n*`"` notation to be used

Comment: Just HTML4.01; HTML4.01+/HTML5 allows it.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I've amended my answer accordingly =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol type="a" start="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, you have to use `<ol start="number">`, but it is deprecated in HTML 4.01 and is not supported in XHTML Strict.

Currently, there is no [CSS Alternative](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_ol_start.asp).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this trick, tested on Firefox, IE6, IE7, Chrome, Safari, Opera :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        li.hidden { list-style: none; position: absolute; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
    <li class="hidden"></li>
    <li class="hidden"></li>
    <li class="hidden"></li>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, any css style besides "display:none" that prevents the list items from being visible will do the work.

Comment: A screenreader would present this as something like: "list, list item one, list item two, list item three, list item four First item, list item five Second item..."